# Capturing XEN Dom0 logs on Debian lenny?

Tags: debian, xen, console, debian-lenny, serial

I have a Dell server with Xen 3.2 (from Debian Lenny) running a Debian Lenny dom0.
Since I am facing unexpected reboot without any clue in the debian logs, I would like to capture the Xen dom0 logs.
Did anybody achieve this and how ?
I tried to use the Dell serial port redirection without success.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with IBM x3850 server. Managed to capture the hypervisor log and kernel log on serial console with these options:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=hvc0 earlyprintk=xen nomodeset initcall_debug debug loglevel=10"
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=9600 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN="dom0_mem=1024M loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all sync_console console_to_ring com1=9600,8n1 console=com1"
```

Options specified as if they are in /etc/default/grub.

Laptop's ttyS0 configured to 9600,8n1

Note that nothing is displayed on server's tty. Adding "vga" to xen consoles list caused no log appear on serial console.